# Set all files in Sharepoint to a specific Sensitivity Label

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have just started with MIP for a site and the customer wants all the labels set in Sharepoint Online to one default Sensitivity label. A few labels are already set, so ultimately all but these ones should be set, but as said few, so I can set them again. How do I do this?

The background why I ask is because I have read in this Microsoft document "Use sensitivity labels to protect content in Microsoft Teams, Microsoft 365 groups, and SharePoint sites", that the files do not inherit the labels if I use them on a container: "Content in these containers however, do not inherit the labels for the classification or settings for files and emails, such as visual markings and encryption." So I guess that means they only apply to the folder, and if the files are moved they do not keep the label?

The other way that I have found that could maybe do what I want is auto-labeling policy. But for starters when I go to Compliance center/Solutions/Information protection, there is no Auto-labeling tab.

So, is there any way that I can do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

**Files&emails** scope configuration lets you have sensitivity labels that are just for documents and emails and can't be selected for containers.

And similarly, sensitivity labels that are just for **containers** and can't be selected for documents and emails.

For your requirements, set the sensitivity label at Files Emails scope only, or set the same label at both scopes.

In addition, Appling a sensitivity label to content automatically is currently **in preview**.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide#label-scopes

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/apply-sensitivity-label-automatically?view=o365-worldwide#how-to-configure-auto-labeling-policies-for-sharepoint-onedrive-and-exchange

Comment: Ok, thank you. I see in your linked text this:
If you don't see the Auto-labeling tab, this functionality isn't currently available in your region.
Is this because it is in preview? And will I then not be able to do this before they let my region have the functionality? In that case, is there any other way?

Comment: Yes you will not able to see this feature until this feature is available in your region, as I entioned above, try to set the same label at both scopes.(Files&emails scope and containers)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

SharePoint seems to have this feature built-in, but it's hard to find.

I read [this link](https://azvise.com/2021/12/10/automatically-apply-sensitivity-label-mdfca/) more carefully, and discovered that you can do this:

1. Open the SharePoint site
2. Do to the document library within it
3. Click the settings gear (upper right)
4. Click "Library settings"
5. Adjust "Default sensitivity labels"

That seems more elegant than the custom policy approach (below), but perhaps they each catch different use cases; I need to experiment more.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I found these, which might help:

- https://blogs.iuvotech.com/protecting-your-data-with-microsofts-sensitivity-labels
- https://azvise.com/2021/12/10/automatically-apply-sensitivity-label-mdfca/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/191908/automatically-apply-a-sensitivity-label-to-all-new (RafaelD's answer on July 26)

They each say the same thing, but they each cover the configuration prerequisites (e.g. allowing Defender for Cloud Apps to scan M365 files) slightly differently.

Comment: And finally found the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-cloud-apps/azip-integration